# Tutorials for simple objects like Railway wagons etc

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

Total beginner. I want to create railway items like wagons, etc. For making .stl files only for 3D printing. No rendering, animation, or anything besides modelling needed.

Can I change the menu to only show the tools I need?
I also need a tutorial to copy over a jpg drawing that gives a side view and end view for reference.
How do I use the tool to extrude, etc? Does this tool have a name?
Show measurements.
How to make different windows etc and place in a library for use as required.

I am 76 and a bit slow on the uptake.  But just the basics is all I need.
Recommended tutorials for me to look at. Thanks. Or even a custom tutorial (you would do this in 5 mins I think !!)
Thank you
-Charles Harris

Comment: Hello, you could start with the basics Here: [Blender Fundamentals](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6)

Answer (score 2):

Different functions of Blenders UI is mainly split into different sections and tabs, if you stick to just the modelling sections you can avoid the clutter of buttons for texturing and rendering. You can add reference images by pressing (Shift)+(A) and going to image>Reference. [image]

To extrude simply select your mesh and press (tab) to enter edit mode. Then select something and press (e) to extrude. You can also snap the extrusion to an axis by pressing x, y, or z.

[image]

To activate tools for measuring you can follow [this simple tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=md403NhvwGg)

I also found a tutorial that leads you through a step by step process of modelling in Blender for a 3D printing purpose. Just click [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqDnLg3o9WE)

If you have any specific questions or need help with how to approach modelling a specific object, feel free to reply to this answer and I can give you some advice.