# Blender Executable file

Tags: linux

[Tutorials for simple objects like Railway wagons etc](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217457/tutorials-for-simple-objects-like-railway-wagons-etc)

Further to above thread. I have downloaded Blender 2.92.   Instruction readme says to right click the executable file.
What is this file called and what extension ?  on Linux Mint 17.       Should I be using 2.80 instead? Where is 2.80 to download (comes up with 2.92 when searching.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Executables on *nix-like Operating Systems in General

*nix-like operating systems usually don't use file extensions to determine if a file is executable or not. Instead they rely on file system flags and file headers (for example ELF headers for binaries and !# - aka Shebang - for shell scripts).

Without going too deep into technical details:

If you download Blender for Linux from blender.org and extract it on any GNU/Linux based operating system, all the necessary flags should be already set. You execute Blender by clicking (single/double depending on your UI settings) on the file called "blender".

[image: Blender 2.92 *nix executable]

Comment: It may be necessary to set the "executable" flag manually in the "permissions" dialog (accessible by right clicking on the "blender" file)

Answer (score 0):

Have tried with  'Blender'     no luck.

I do have one other file in this folder that is not in your folder  --  file:///home/charles7/Documents/Blender/Program%202.92/blender-2.92.0-linux64/%01%BA%DB%EA@%B0͔%0E@8

Whatever that means.
Keep in mind I am using a 32 bit laptop, should this load onto it?

Charles

Comment: If your OS is 32 bit, it won't be able to run 64bit-Applications. It seems that the last 32-bit release of blender is https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/